# Debug RailsAdmin error which causes transaction rollback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rails-admin

I'm trying to solve a current issue on my rails app. My rails app is using RailsAdmin and I have an issue after trying to upload files via generic RailsAdmin options.

So this app is using Ruby 2.5.3, RailsAdmin 1.4.2 and Rails 5.2.3.

It seems that I'm running in a silent error ... maybe a kind of model validation or something like that buy I even don't get any relevant output on debug mode.

The problem is that I have no certain idea how I should proceed on debugging this problem because these actions are handled within the rails-admin gem.
Even though I'm using RubyMine with the debugging feature I have no clue where to set the breakpoints because this is handled be the gem. I've tried to break on some initializers but of course that didn't had the intended effect.

So **I would appreciate any hints and help which supports me debugging this problem!**

Best regards,

Tunnelblick

---

Debug output:

```
Started POST "/administrator/document/new" for <src_ip> at 2019-09-03 11:47:46 +0200
Processing by RailsAdmin::MainController#new as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"<token>", "document"=>{"title"=>"Testimage", "description"=>"", "page_ids"=>["", "", "151"], "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f4ebbf196e8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20190903-3614-gbt3ad.png>, @original_filename="generic_testimage.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"document[file]\"; filename=\"generic_testimage.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}, "remotipart_submitted"=>"true", "X-Requested-With"=>"IFrame", "X-HTTP-Accept"=>"text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01", "model_name"=>"document"}
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  ↳ config/initializers/rails_admin.rb:97
   (0.9ms)  SELECT `user_roles`.`role_id` FROM `user_roles` WHERE `user_roles`.`user_id` = 1
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:236
   (0.5ms)  SELECT `roles`.`name` FROM `roles` WHERE `roles`.`id` = 1
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:236
  Disk Storage (4.5ms) Uploaded file to key: HsSaBijYwg3JLeR8dV7akmpF (checksum: /QSj27UArM/yWCLulQaTpA==)
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ /home/testvm01/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@<gemset>/bundler/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-1105d02d6284/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/transaction.rb:38
  ActiveStorage::Blob Create (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO `active_storage_blobs` (`key`, `filename`, `content_type`, `metadata`, `byte_size`, `checksum`, `created_at`) VALUES ('HsSaBijYwg3JLeR8dV7akmpF', 'generic_testimage.png', 'image/png', '{\"identified\":true}', 2673, '/QSj27UArM/yWCLulQaTpA==', '2019-09-03 09:47:46')
  ↳ /home/testvm01/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@<gemset>/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
   (3.6ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ /home/testvm01/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@<gemset>/bundler/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-1105d02d6284/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/transaction.rb:42
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ /home/testvm01/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@<gemset>/bundler/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-1105d02d6284/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/transaction.rb:38
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ /home/testvm01/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@<gemset>/bundler/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-1105d02d6284/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/transaction.rb:42
  Page Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `pages`.* FROM `pages` WHERE `pages`.`id` = 151
  ↳ /home/testvm01/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@<gemset>/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ /home/testvm01/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@<gemset>/bundler/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-1105d02d6284/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/transaction.rb:38


   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK


  ↳ /home/testvm01/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@<gemset>/bundler/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-1105d02d6284/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/transaction.rb:47
  Rendering /home/testvm01/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@<gemset>/gems/rails_admin-1.4.2/app/views/rails_admin/main/new.html.haml
  Rendered /home/testvm01/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@<gemset>/gems/rails_admin-1.4.2/app/views/rails_admin/main/_form_field.html.haml (3.9ms)
  Rendered /home/testvm01/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@<gemset>/gems/rails_admin-1.4.2/app/views/rails_admin/main/_form_text.html.haml (3.6ms)
  Rendered /home/testvm01/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@<gemset>/gems/rails_admin-1.4.2/app/views/rails_admin/main/_form_file_upload.html.haml (7.8ms)
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `pages`
  ↳ /home/testvm01/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@<gemset>/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `pages`
  ↳ /home/testvm01/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@<gemset>/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  Rendered /home/testvm01/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@<gemset>/gems/rails_admin-1.4.2/app/views/rails_admin/main/_form_filtering_multiselect.html.haml (15.9ms)
  Rendered /home/testvm01/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@<gemset>/gems/rails_admin-1.4.2/app/views/rails_admin/main/_submit_buttons.html.haml (14.2ms)
  Rendered /home/testvm01/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@<gemset>/gems/rails_admin-1.4.2/app/views/rails_admin/main/new.html.haml (70.9ms)
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 124ms (Views: 76.5ms | ActiveRecord: 8.8ms)


<src_ip> - - [03/Sep/2019:11:47:46 CEST] "POST /administrator/document/new HTTP/1.1" 406 5828
http://<dst_ip>:3000/administrator/Page/151/edit -> /administrator/document/new
Started GET "/rails/active_storage/representations/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBb1VEIiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--01b687f90aa49f3bfd52fe06cfb950eef8711461/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdCam9MY21WemFYcGxTU0lOTVRBd2VERXdNRDRHT2daRlZBPT0iLCJleHAiOm51bGwsInB1ciI6InZhcmlhdGlvbiJ9fQ==--597b84b3c8f143e08ed73e02d88e0aee694d1066/generic_testimage.png" for <src_ip> at 2019-09-03 11:47:46 +0200
Processing by ActiveStorage::RepresentationsController#show as PNG
  Parameters: {"signed_blob_id"=>"eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBb1VEIiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--01b687f90aa49f3bfd52fe06cfb950eef8711461", "variation_key"=>"eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdCam9MY21WemFYcGxTU0lOTVRBd2VERXdNRDRHT2daRlZBPT0iLCJleHAiOm51bGwsInB1ciI6InZhcmlhdGlvbiJ9fQ==--597b84b3c8f143e08ed73e02d88e0aee694d1066", "filename"=>"generic_testimage"}
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (2.5ms)  SELECT  `active_storage_blobs`.* FROM `active_storage_blobs` WHERE `active_storage_blobs`.`id` = 901 LIMIT 1
  ↳ /home/testvm01/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@<gemset>/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  Disk Storage (0.1ms) Checked if file exists at key: variants/HsSaBijYwg3JLeR8dV7akmpF/64ff10e27609a8b1f320398d41a1f5791aeb2e108f429b203d5f3c650e0b744d (no)
  Disk Storage (0.1ms) Downloaded file from key: HsSaBijYwg3JLeR8dV7akmpF
  Disk Storage (0.3ms) Uploaded file to key: variants/HsSaBijYwg3JLeR8dV7akmpF/64ff10e27609a8b1f320398d41a1f5791aeb2e108f429b203d5f3c650e0b744d
  Disk Storage (0.8ms) Generated URL for file at key: variants/HsSaBijYwg3JLeR8dV7akmpF/64ff10e27609a8b1f320398d41a1f5791aeb2e108f429b203d5f3c650e0b744d (http://<dst_ip>:3000/rails/active_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--c5bcf6d4ef2e2800968e21be38b234711a8d43a9/generic_testimage.png?content_type=image%2Fpng&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22generic_testimage.png%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27generic_testimage.png)
Redirected to http://<dst_ip>:3000/rails/active_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--c5bcf6d4ef2e2800968e21be38b234711a8d43a9/generic_testimage.png?content_type=image%2Fpng&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22generic_testimage.png%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27generic_testimage.png
Completed 302 Found in 72ms (ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)


<src_ip> - - [03/Sep/2019:11:47:46 CEST] "GET /rails/active_storage/representations/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBb1VEIiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--01b687f90aa49f3bfd52fe06cfb950eef8711461/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdCam9MY21WemFYcGxTU0lOTVRBd2VERXdNRDRHT2daRlZBPT0iLCJleHAiOm51bGwsInB1ciI6InZhcmlhdGlvbiJ9fQ==--597b84b3c8f143e08ed73e02d88e0aee694d1066/generic_testimage.png HTTP/1.1" 302 863
http://<dst_ip>:3000/administrator/Page/151/edit -> /rails/active_storage/representations/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBb1VEIiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--01b687f90aa49f3bfd52fe06cfb950eef8711461/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdCam9MY21WemFYcGxTU0lOTVRBd2VERXdNRDRHT2daRlZBPT0iLCJleHAiOm51bGwsInB1ciI6InZhcmlhdGlvbiJ9fQ==--597b84b3c8f143e08ed73e02d88e0aee694d1066/generic_testimage.png
Started GET "/rails/active_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--c5bcf6d4ef2e2800968e21be38b234711a8d43a9/generic_testimage.png?content_type=image%2Fpng&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22generic_testimage.png%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27generic_testimage.png" for <src_ip> at 2019-09-03 11:47:46 +0200
Processing by ActiveStorage::DiskController#show as PNG
  Parameters: {"content_type"=>"image/png", "disposition"=>"inline; filename=\"generic_testimage.png\"; filename*=UTF-8''generic_testimage.png", "encoded_key"=>"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--c5bcf6d4ef2e2800968e21be38b234711a8d43a9", "filename"=>"generic_testimage"}
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


<src_ip> - - [03/Sep/2019:11:47:46 CEST] "GET /rails/active_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--c5bcf6d4ef2e2800968e21be38b234711a8d43a9/generic_testimage.png?content_type=image%2Fpng&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22generic_testimage.png%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27generic_testimage.png HTTP/1.1" 200 830
http://<dst_ip>:3000/administrator/Page/151/edit -> /rails/active_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--c5bcf6d4ef2e2800968e21be38b234711a8d43a9/generic_testimage.png?content_type=image%2Fpng&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22generic_testimage.png%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27generic_testimage.png
```

---

RailsAdmin MainController

```
RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.all.each do |action|
      class_eval <<-EOS, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
        def #{action.action_name}
          action = RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.find('#{action.action_name}'.to_sym)
          @authorization_adapter.try(:authorize, action.authorization_key, @abstract_model, @object)
          @action = action.with({controller: self, abstract_model: @abstract_model, object: @object})
          fail(ActionNotAllowed) unless @action.enabled?
          @page_name = wording_for(:title)

          instance_eval &@action.controller
        end
      EOS
    end
```

Comment: Looks like while trying to save active_storage_blobs you are running into some validation error.
Please also add controller side code

Comment: Hi @Surya, this is part of the RailsAdmin and not directly processed by my application's controllers.

See: 
`Processing by RailsAdmin::MainController#new as JS`

Comment: @Surya I've added the relevant part of the RailsAdmin's MainController

Comment: You could override `document/new` method of RailsAdmin and then use `scope` to limit the users based on the condition

Comment: If you need help on how to do this let me know

Comment: @Surya I'm trying to track this down with my debugger ... I've set breakpoints in this RailsAdmin code now ... let's see

Comment: As per RailsAdmin's logic they will be displaying all of users, you need to change RailsAdmins code and restrict limit users. So you need to `monkey patch` raisl admin code, which is a simple thing only. In RailsAdmin github page check the implementation of this function `document/new `

Comment: I really don't get why I you proposed me to do this. @Surya